# How do edit file path value to accept variables within the TFS build definition in xml?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have looked through Goolge but have failed to find results.

The reason I want to do this in xml view is because the designer view does not register the following xml:

**Code Snippet 1**

```
<aa1:RenameFile FilePath="\\BuildServer1\Website\web.config" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" NewFilePath="\\BuildServer1\Website\web.config" 
xmlns:aa1="clr-namespace:AssemblyVersion.Activities;assembly=CustomActivities" />
```

But even with this problem, this code works.

I want to change the above xml to something like this:

**Code Snippet 2**

```
<aa1:RenameFile 
FilePath="WebConfigFolderLocation + &quot;\&quot; + OldFileName" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" 
NewFilePath="WebConfigFolderLocation + &quot;\&quot; + OldFileName + &quot;TemporaryFile2014&quot;" 
xmlns:aa1="clr-namespace:AssemblyVersion.Activities;assembly=CustomActivities" />
```

But when I do this I get the following error:

*Illegal characters in path*

**Can anyone spot anything wrong with my amendments in Code Snippet 2?**

Note: aa1 is define as:

```
xmlns:aa1="clr-namespace:AssemblyVersion.Activities;assembly=CustomActivities"
```

Answer (score 0):

**I changed code snippet 2 to:**

```
<aa1:RenameFile FilePath="[WebConfigFolderLocation &amp; &quot;\&quot; &amp; OldFileName]" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" NewFilePath="[WebConfigFolderLocation &amp; &quot;\&quot; &amp; OldFileName &amp; &quot;TemporaryFile2014&quot;]" 
xmlns:aa1="clr-namespace:AssemblyVersion.Activities;assembly=CustomActivities" />
```

**In summary I just replaced all '+' with '&amp ;' (I put space inbetween 'p' and ';' because stackoverflow renders it as & otherwise) and I also encapsulated the FilePath and NewFilePath value with square brackets.**

Not sure I understand why I need square brackets here but it works now. Thank you me!